# Using javascript to check if rows are empty in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using javascript to check if table rows are empty. In case they are empty it should give the user a pop up message, otherwise redirect. I've been trying this, but what it does is to give me the alert message whether or not something is in the row.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function onSubmit() {
    var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
    if (rowCount < 0) {

            location.href = '@Url.Action("","")';

        }
        else {

            alert("No item was added");
        }
}

<table id ="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Customer Number</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Customer Description</th>
                        <th class="col-md-3">Expense Account</th>

                    </tr>
                    @{
                        if (@Model.Customers.Count > 0)
```

{

```
foreach (var Customer in @Model.Customers)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-md-2">@Customer.CustomerNumber</td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">@Customer.description</td>
                                <td class="col-md-3">@Customer.expense_account.getDescription</td>

                            </tr>**

    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit" margin="50px" onclick="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` condition is wrong!. With your current code, if the row count is **zero or more**(*else part*), you are showing the alert. As per your question, you want to show the alert when there are no rows ,except the header row.

So check the rowcount is 1, that means you only have header row, so show the error message, else redirect.

```
function onSubmit() {
    var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
        if (rowCount === 1) {
            alert("No item was added");
         }
        else {
           location.href = '@Url.Action("SomeActionMethod","SomeController")';
        }
 }
```

**Or** you can specifically check for the number rows in the table body and check the count against 0

```
function onSubmit() {
    var rowCount = $('#myTable >tbody >tr').length;
        if (rowCount ===0) {
            alert("No item was added");
         }
        else {
           location.href = '@Url.Action("SomeActionMethod","SomeController")';
        }
 }
```

Comment: it just redirect; when  there is no data and when there is data but I want to give the alert message when there's no data

Comment: @Lenny Are you sure you have code same as what i have in the answer ? ( my if condition checks for 1 row)

Comment: It just jump to the else part; yes I have it the exact same way

Comment: three equal signs?

Comment: Yes, `===` equals to compare when you know the types are equal (numbers in this case).  What is the rowCount you are getting ?

Comment: zero is what I get even when I add data

Comment: So are you saying that the code `$('#myTable tr').length` is giving you `0` even when you have records in your table. That is impossible. It will not give you `0` at all as you have a header row. Check the view source of the page and see how many DOM elements in your page has the Id value `myTable`. You should have only one

Comment: when I put in tbody it gives when there is no data and 3 if there is data

Comment: So what is the problem ? If you get the correct rowCount value, the if condition should work fine. It is just simple

Answer (score 0):

> Try This hope it will work

```
function onSubmit() {
    var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length-1;
        if (rowCount ==0) {
            alert("No item was added");
         }
        else {
           location.href = '@Url.Action("","")';
        }
 }
```